# Creating Discord Bot method that moves messages as embeded message

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been learning how to code a discord bot recently and I've hit a wall. I am wanting to create a method that allows me to move messages from one channel to another. I created a solution that works but not how I would like it to. Idealy I would want to just have the bot almost do a reddit repost where it takes the exact message and just has it embedded. Currently what I have for the method is

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    content = message.context
    channel = message.channel

    if message.content.startswith('!move'):
        #code to process the input, nothing special or important to this
        for i in fetchedMessages:
            embededMessage = discord.Embed()
            embededMessage.description = i.context
            embededMessage.set_author(name=i.author, icon_url=i.author.avatar_url)
            await channelToPostIn.send(embeded=embededMessage)
            # delete the old message
            i.delete()
```

Now this works perfectly for text messages but not for images or for example if the post was embedded in the first place. If someone has a more elegant solution or is able to point me in the right direction in the documentation I would be much appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: this is quite unclear, do you want to embed a message when you pass in its ID or reply to it or every message in a channel?

Comment: I am uncertain about your question

Comment: what arguments would you provide to this command

Comment: Oh I see, an example of how this would be used is: !move {name of channel to move to} {number of messages to be moved}. So if I do !move move-to 3 it will move the last three messages from the channel it is sent in to the move-to channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Buster's solution worked correctly except for when a user uploaded a picture as a file attached to the message. To fix this I ended up setting the image of the embedded message with the proxy_url of the image attached. my whole move command is as followed.

```
# Move: !move {channel to move to} {number of messages}
# Used to move messages from one channel to another.
@client.command(name='move')
async def move(context):

    if "mod" not in [y.name.lower() for y in context.message.author.roles]:
        await context.message.delete()
        await context.channel.send("{} you do not have the permissions to move messages.".format(context.message.author))
        return

    # get the content of the message
    content = context.message.content.split(' ')
    # if the length is not three the command was used incorrectly
    if len(content) != 3 or not content[2].isnumeric():
        await context.message.channel.send("Incorrect usage of !move. Example: !move {channel to move to} {number of messages}.")
        return
    # channel that it is going to be posted to
    channelTo = content[1]
    # get the number of messages to be moved (including the command message)
    numberOfMessages = int(content[2]) + 1
    # get a list of the messages
    fetchedMessages = await context.channel.history(limit=numberOfMessages).flatten()
    
    # delete all of those messages from the channel
    for i in fetchedMessages:
        await i.delete()

    # invert the list and remove the last message (gets rid of the command message)
    fetchedMessages = fetchedMessages[::-1]
    fetchedMessages = fetchedMessages[:-1]

    # Loop over the messages fetched
    for messages in fetchedMessages:
        # get the channel object for the server to send to
        channelTo = discord.utils.get(messages.guild.channels, name=channelTo)

        # if the message is embeded already
        if messages.embeds:
            # set the embed message to the old embed object
            embedMessage = messages.embeds[0]
        # else
        else:
            # Create embed message object and set content to original
            embedMessage = discord.Embed(
                        description = messages.content
                        )
            # set the embed message author to original author
            embedMessage.set_author(name=messages.author, icon_url=messages.author.avatar_url)
            # if message has attachments add them
            if messages.attachments:
                for i in messages.attachments:
                    embedMessage.set_image(url = i.proxy_url)

        # Send to the desired channel
        await channelTo.send(embed=embedMessage)
```

Thanks to everyone that helped with this problem.

Comment: By using arguments that way you kind of ruin the usefulness of a `Bot.command`...

Comment: Care to explain? Your comment provides no information to help myself or any reader that  might read in the future. If you do not want to explain please refrain from posting comments like this on post.

Comment: You don't have to be so impertinent about it, my example should explain it. I also told you to check out a basic bot from the discord.py documentation, that should also explain it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my solution. Your solution worked but did not accommodate files, mine did. So for any person in the future that would be looking on a solution that accommodated files as my initial problem was, they would have a solution to look at.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot easier if you were to use the `commands.Bot` extension: [`discord.ext.commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=discord%20ext%20commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) (check out a [basic bot](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py))

```py
bot = commands.Bot(...)

@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *message_ids: int): # Typehint to a Messageable
    '''Moves the message content to another channel'''
    # Loop over each message id provided
    for message_id in message_ids:
        # Holds the Message instance that should be moved
        message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)

        # It is possible the bot fails to fetch the message, if it has been deleted for example
        if not message:
            return

        # Check if message has an embed (only webhooks can send multiple in one message)
        if message.embeds:
            # Just copy the embed including all its properties
            embed = message.embeds[0]
            # Overwrite their title
            embed.title = f'Embed by: {message.author}'

        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=f'Message by: {message.author}',
                description=message.content
            )

        # send the message to specified channel
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        # delete the original
        await message.delete()
```

Possible problems:

- The message has both an embed and content (easy fix, just add the message.content to the embed.description, and check whether the length isn't over the limit)
- The command isn't used in the channel where the message resides, so it can't find the message (can be fixed by specifying a channel to search the message in, instead of using Context)
- A video being in an embed, I am unsure what would happen with for example a youtube link that is embedded, as a bot can't embed videos afaik

Comment: This looks like an excellent answer, thank you. I haven't implemented it yet because I'm learning now about commands. Would this solution work if the message contained an image? I saw your potential problem with videos and I am unsure if they are handled similarly. Thanks

Comment: It works with images, It might not work with videos, as they aren't accessible for bots/users. P.S If this works, make sure to mark it as answered :)

Comment: Your solution did work but I ran into the same problem I was having before where a user uploads an image. It is treated different from a reaction or gif from discord. I'll post the solution that I came up with.